# Why is Java saying my constructor is undefined even though it is?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm getting an error message in Dr. Java saying my constructor is undefined for String, int, int, despite the fact that my constructor has those parameters(in the same order) and everything is case matching. it's also not an issue of one class having an out of date save like another thread suggested.

Here is my "Mall" class with the constructor accepting a string an int and an int

```
public class Mall{
  //declare variables
  private String name;//name of the mall
  private int length; //length of the mall = # of columns of stores array
  private int width; //width of the mall = # of rows of stores array


  public void Mall(String name, int length, int width){
   //this is the constructor I want to use
   this.name=name;
   this.length=length;
   this.width=width;
  }
 }
```

and here is my main method

```
public class Test1{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Mall m = new Mall("nameOfMall", 3, 3); //here is where the error happens
 }
}
```

I've tried creating a constructor with no parameters as well and then passing no parameters in my object creation statement and while that doesn't result in any compilations errors it doesn't set it to the proper values either. Also I can call other methods in the Mall class just fine which leads me to believe it's an issue with my creation statement rather than anything in the Mall class. Am I right to think that? What's causing the error?

Comment: I don't see any constructors. (Hint: `void`. Voting to close as typo.)

Comment: The word `void` makes Java understand the following as a method, not as a constructor. A constructor does not have a return type at all.

Comment: What you have there is a _method_, not a _constructor_. The `public void (...` tells Java that this is a mehod which does not return a value, hence the `void`. If you want a constructor, use `public MyConstructor (...` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have a method instead of a constructor. A constructor des not have `void`.

This is a method:

```
public void Mall(String name, int length, int width){
   this.length=length;
   this.width=width;
}
```

This is a constructor:

```
public Mall(String name, int length, int width)
{
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the return type `void` from your constructor.

More detailed info on constructors is: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: That link is *not* to the JLS.

Comment: I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `void`

```
  Mall(String name, int length, int width){
   //this is the constructor I want to use
   this.name=name;
   this.length=length;
   this.width=width;
  }
```